# Nonlinear parameters search

Tags: matlab, parameters, nonlinear-functions

need to find a set of optimal parameters P of the system y = P(1)*exp(-P(2)*x) - P(3)*x where x and y are experimental values. I defined my function

```
f = @(P) P(1)*exp(-P(2)*x) - P(3)*x
```

and

```
guess = [1, 1, 1]
```

and tried

```
P = fminsearch(f,guess)
```

according to Help. I get an error

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in fminsearch (line 191) 
>   fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

I don't quite understand where my y values would fall in, as well as where the function takes P from. I unfortunately have no access to `nlinfit` or optimization toolboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the matlab function **lsqnonlin(@testfun,[1;1;1])**
But first make a function and save in an m-file that includes all the data points, lets say your y is A and x is x like here below:

```
function F = testfun(P)
A = [1;2;3;7;30;100];
x = [1;2;3;4;5;6];
F = A-P(1)*exp(-P(2)*x) - P(3)*x;
```

This minimized the 2-norm end gives you the best parameters.

Comment: I only have lsqnonneg.

Comment: get the optimization toolbox for matlab if you can

Comment: I wrote I don't have it.

Comment: implement this then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm

Comment: If you don't wan't to do that, I suppose you could take the log of your function and then use C\d in Matlab where C is a matrix of the coefficients of P and d is the log(y)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are negative values.